# How to find the value in the cell above 3 searched-for numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to search a list of numbers for a sub-list of other numbers. If the sub-list is found, in the same order, then return the value in the cell immediately above the found sub-list.

If I use this formala
`=INDEX(B3:B15,MATCH(D3,B3:B15,0)-1,1)`
(Consider data table in B column,  i entered the below formula in output),

Output is showing for only one number.

But, I need the output for all 3 consecutive numbers, not for each..If I enter 4,2,9 in"3 numbers" cells, the output should show for that 3 numbers.

In the example below, I search for the three numbers 4,2,9. I find those numbers the first time, and return the 4 highlighted yellow since it is above where I found the numbers. I also return the 6 highlighted in yellow, since it is found above the three numbers I searched for.

[image: Click here for sample data]

Comment: The output should be shown on the same cell or different cells?

Comment: Same cell or different cell ..no problem

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over. This is the third time. I already told you ... Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of What does it mean if a question is "closed"?. If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill Can I try to answer the question?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Of course, I was warning the OP about reposting his question. That doesn't mean you can't answer *this* one :)

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you expect for output for the data sample given?.  Also what version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a macro to find the numbers. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. The VBE editor will open. Right-click "This Workbook", then select Insert and select Module. Enter the following code and press <kbd>F5</kbd> (or the "Play" button) to run it. You can also start the macro by going to the Developer tab of the ribbon, click on Macros, select `Find3Numbers`, then click on `Run`.

```
Sub FindNumberAbove3Cells()

    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim fvalue, svalue, tvalue As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    'Clear the cells
    Range("F4") = ""
    Range("F5") = ""
    Range("F6") = ""

    found = False

    fvalue = Range("D4")
    svalue = Range("D5")
    tvalue = Range("D6")

    i = 4
    j = 4
    
    Do
        'Check if the 3 cells contain the 3 numbers we are searching
        If (Range("B" & i) = fvalue) And (Range("B" & (i + 1)) = svalue) And (Range("B" & (i + 2)) = tvalue) Then
            'Check of the content of the previous cell is a number
            If IsNumeric(Range("B" & (i - 1))) Then
                Range("F" & j) = Range("B" & (i - 1))
                j = j + 1
                found = True
            End If
        End If

        i = i + 1

        'Exit the loop when one of consecutive cells is empty
    Loop While Range("B" & (i + 2)) <> ""

    'If there are not values above the 3 consecutive cells, print #N/A on cell F4
    If found = False Then
        Range("F" & j) = "#N/A"

    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Results when numbers are found**

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

**Results when numbers are not found**

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you, But if criteria is (4,2,9), output should be (4,6)..Same as @FlexYourData formula & result

Comment: @ganesh26066 See changes made to the macro.

Comment: Thanks, if more than 4 criteria , can i know what to do..

Comment: @ganesh26066 You must declare another variable and use it with the IF statement. You must add "(Range("B" & (i + 1)) = anothervalue)",. "Anothervalue" will be the variable you declared

Comment: Thanks, it is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Something I won't be able to test since I don't have O365 and Excel Online won't have `FILTERXML`, but in `E2` try:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,IF(MID(CONCAT(A2:A14),SEQUENCE(13),3)=CONCAT(C2:C4),INDEX(A1:A13,SEQUENCE(13)),""))&"</s></t>","//s")
```

Something I could test Online was (the more ugly)

```
=FILTER(IF(MID(CONCAT(A2:A14),SEQUENCE(13),3)=CONCAT(C2:C4),INDEX(A1:A13,SEQUENCE(13)),""),IF(MID(CONCAT(A2:A14),SEQUENCE(13),3)=CONCAT(C2:C4),INDEX(A1:A13,SEQUENCE(13)),"")<>"")
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As I understand the goal, you want to find the searched list of numbers within a longer list. If you find the searched for list, return the number in the cell above the found list from the longer list.

I decided to break the problem down into a few steps. First, a formula to find the list of three numbers. This uses OFFSET and is somewhat tied to it being 3 numbers, but it works and can be expanded if necessary.

This is the formula in column D of my image:

```
=AND(C4=$A$4,OFFSET(C4,1,0)=OFFSET($A$4,1,0),OFFSET(C4,2,0)=OFFSET($A$4,2,0))
```

The formula basically says "If the value in the current row (4) in column C, is equal to the first value in the list in column A, and the value below that is equal to the 2nd value, and the value below *that* is equal to the 3rd value, then TRUE, otherwise FALSE". By dragging down, we have a column of TRUE and FALSE. A TRUE indicates the top of the found sub-list.

To get the numbers above the found sub-list, we can use OFFSET again. The formula in column E in my image is:

```
=IF(D4,OFFSET(C4,-1,0),"")
```

So, if column D is TRUE (we've found the sublist), get the value from the cell in the row above.

You can combine the formulas from columns D and E into a single formula:

```
=IF(AND($C4=$A$4,OFFSET($C4,1,0)=OFFSET($A$4,1,0),OFFSET($C4,2,0)=OFFSET($A$4,2,0)),OFFSET($C4,-1,0),"")
```

If you need to return the output into a short list of contiguous cells, you can use this if you have a version older than Excel 365:

```
={IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF($E$3:$E$16,"?*")<1,"",INDEX(E:E,SMALL(IF($E$3:$E$16<>"",ROW($E$3:$E$16)),ROWS(E$3:E3)))),"")}
```

(which is difficult and obscure, to be honest)

[image]

Or if you have the latest version of Excel 365 and can use dynamic arrays, you can just use this:

```
=FILTER($E$4:$E$16,$E$4:$E$16<>"")
```

Of course, that can be done on columns E or F.

EDIT:

To extend this to a list of four numbers, simply add a new clause to the AND function:

```
=IF(AND($C4=$A$4,OFFSET($C4,1,0)=OFFSET($A$4,1,0),OFFSET($C4,2,0)=OFFSET($A$4,2,0),OFFSET($C4,3,0)=OFFSET($A$4,3,0)),OFFSET($C4,-1,0),"")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its Solved my problem

Comment: If i need to find for 4 numbers(4,2,9,0).. what will be the formula?

Comment: @ganesh26066, I'm glad it solved your problem. I've put an EDIT in my answer to show you how to find a list of four numbers. Please accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem.